# How to get the gmpy2 module in RPI2 Buildroot

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi2, gmp, buildroot, gmpy

I am unable to get the gmpy2 Python module working in a Buildroot build for Raspberry Pi2. Buildroot does not include the gmpy2 module by default.

Buildroot does not include the GCC as well, so I compiled the gmpy2 module from source on Raspbian on another RPI2 board (having the same Python version -- 3.7.2 -- as the Buildroot board) and copied the resulting `gmpy2.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so` to  Buildroot board's /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ and put a link `gmpy2.so` in the same directory.

I expected Python to be able to see the module, but instead I get:

```
# python3
Python 3.7.2 (default, Apr 10 2019, 23:36:01)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gmpy2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: File not found
>>>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an actual Buildroot package for gmpy2, it should be sufficient to run `utils/scanpypi gmpy2`. Make sure that `package/python-gmpy2/Config.in` is sourced from `package/Config.in`, then you can select it in the normal way from menuconfig.

If it all works, please [send the patch to the Buildroot mailing list](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#submitting-patches) for upstream inclusion. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I had to add `PYTHON_GMPY2_EXTRACT_CMDS = unzip` to `package/python-gmpy2/python-gmpy2.mk` because the sources from PyPI are zipped.